# Position of row fragment being reset to 0

Tags: android, leanback

In my app I have a number of row fragments on the homepage all contained in a BrowseFragment. The top row is a carousel, so I extended ArrayObjectAdapter so that it sets the start index to Integer.MAX_VALUE/2 and returns items based on the modulous of the selected index. The issue that I am having is that when going to rows further down the page (far enough that the carousel is off-screen) and then go back up the page to bring the carousel back on-screen, the index for the carousel is reset to 0. I'm having a hard time tracking down this bug because it seems like all indexing is handled by the Leanback library.

Has anyone else seen this error and/or have any idea how to fix it? If there's any other info that you need I'll do my best to provide it, but I don't know what could be handling position tracking other than Leanback.

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue with Leanback library

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I ever found a good fix for this :/

Comment: have you found a solution already?

Comment: Sadly no... Since it was only a visual bug and was eating up a lot of dev time it was decided that we'd have to publish the app with that in there :/